# How create custom validation for Validators.required

Tags: angular

I want to create a method for validations who will be executed before touch my input text files. Example:
I want to create method `checkMyArray()` and when the array is empty return false/ when the array is not empty return true.

```
  'image': new FormControl(image, checkMyArray().bind(this))
```

Comment: Kindly explain and provide more details

Comment: I set more details for this post. Now is understandable?

Comment: (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html) This is a good article about building custom validators.